# Как выбрать минимальные даты в периоде

Tags: sql, oracle

Добрый день требуется выбрать минимальную дату в интервале даты +-7 дней

```
id  number      date
1   97236732    07.06.0023
2   97236732    09.06.0023
3   97236732    09.06.0023
4   97236732    21.06.0023
```

Т.е пофакту требуется чтобы были записи 1 и 4 из таблицы

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. А как определять границы интервала? Если, скажем, есть 10 записей, дни подряд - какие из них должны вернуться?

Comment: Границы интервала это +- 7 дней от даты записи т.е. по факту 09.06.2023 то фактически  интервал от этой даты  будет с 02.06.2023 по 16.06.2023, соответственно если даты попадают в данный интервал, то мне нужна запись с минимальной датой

Comment: дополню комментарий...

Comment: нужна запись с минимальным значением  если несколько записей в периоде, и соответственно если запись одна то эта единственная запись так же нужна

Comment: *если несколько записей в периоде* Как именно определить границы периода? *т.е. по факту 09.06.2023 то фактически интервал от этой даты будет с 02.06.2023 по 16.06.2023* Почему именно 09.06.2023? Откуда взялось это значение?

Comment: Попробую по другому ответить.
Если запись 2 попадает в интервал -+ 7 дней от записи 1 то тогда требуется вывести запись 1

Comment: Уже лучше. То есть берём самую старую (первую) запись, от неё 7 дней и все записи в этом диапазоне - её соседи, а она - наименьшая, её вернуть, остальные отбросить. Затем то же проделаем с оставшимися. И так, пока записи не кончатся. Верно?

Comment: Да все верно, надо именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможная реализация:

```
WITH
source (dt) AS (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
 ),
recurse (dt, step) AS (
  SELECT dt, 1
  FROM source
  UNION ALL
  SELECT source.dt, recurse.step + 1
  FROM source
  JOIN recurse ON source.dt >= recurse.dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(dt), 'YYYY-MM-DD') dt
FROM recurse
GROUP BY step
```

| DT |
| --- |
| 2023-01-01 |
| 2023-01-09 |
| 2023-01-16 |
| 2023-01-27 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4kVg-NtY)